# How to create a trigger that tracks changes to specific columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

In a **PostgreSQL** database I have a table called `SURVEYS` which looks like this:

```
| ID (uuid)                            | name (varchar) | status (boolean) | update_at (timestamp)    |  
|--------------------------------------|----------------|------------------|--------------------------|
| 9bef1274-f1ee-4879-a60e-16e94e88df38 | Doom           | 1                | 2019-03-26 00:00:00      |
```

As you can see, the table has the columns `status` and `update_at`.

My task is to create a trigger that will start the function if the user updates the value in `status` column to `2` and changes the value in the `update_at` column. In the function I would use the ID of the entry which was changed. I created such a trigger. Do you think is it correct to check column values in the trigger, or do I need to check it in the function? I am little bit confused.

```
CREATE TRIGGER СHECK_FOR_UPDATES_IN_SURVEYS
BEFORE UPDATE ON SURVEYS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN 
  (OLD.update_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.update_at)
AND 
  (OLD.condition IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.condition AND NEW.condition = 2)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE CREATE_SURVEYS_QUESTIONS_RELATIONSHIP(NEW.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger looks just fine.

There is only one slight syntax problem: the whole `WHEN` clause has to be surrounded by parentheses.

Also, you cannot pass anything but a constant to the trigger function. But you don't have to do that at all: `NEW` will be available in the trigger function automatically.

So you could write it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER СHECK_FOR_UPDATES_IN_SURVEYS
BEFORE UPDATE ON SURVEYS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN 
  (OLD.update_at IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.update_at
   AND
   OLD.condition IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.condition AND NEW.condition = 2)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE CREATE_SURVEYS_QUESTIONS_RELATIONSHIP();
```

It is always preferable to check conditions in the trigger definition, because that will save you unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Hello! I tried to create trigger by code which you can see in post. Unfortunately it raise error `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AND"`. I am confused. Where exactly I made error for your opinion?

Comment: There was a small syntax problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: As you can see I am trying to pass `NEW.id` value as function argument. How do you think, why I have syntax error `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."` in that place.

Comment: I should read more carefully :^( You can only specify constants as argument in `CREATE TRIGGER`. They will show up in `TG_ARGV` in the trigger. But you don't have to pass `NEW` at all, just omit it. `NEW` is available inside the trigger function automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! I created trigger but I am confused. So you mean that I can use id of edited entry inside procedure, right?

Comment: Finally I found the solution for last my comment. I use `NEW.id` value in procedure.